# Kit Scenarist is not installing in Debian-testing

Tags: debian, qt

sudo apt install kitscenarist
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kitscenarist : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-11-3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

On debian, the package `kitscenarist` is only available for debian 10 from KITScenarist  repository and [here is how to install it](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AAndnoVember%3AKITScenarist&package=kitscenarist):

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/AndnoVember:/KITScenarist/Debian_10/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:AndnoVember:KITScenarist.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:AndnoVember:KITScenarist/Debian_10/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_AndnoVember_KITScenarist.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kitscenarist
```

[Supported linux versions](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/AndnoVember:/KITScenarist/)